# ¿cómo se pueden sumar filas agrupadas?

Tags: postgresql

Se puede emplear esta formula para sumar las cifras que resulten .

```
ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(pos_payment.amount),' , ')

|  columna1   |   columna2
|    3        |     33 , 01
|    8        |     20, -4,76
|    1897     |    200 , -25,76
```

que se agrupe por 3 y salga 33,1 o por 8 y se vea 15,24  o en el caso de 1897 , 174,24

Answer (score 1):

Si en la segunda columna tienes una lista de valores separados por ', ' (coma y espacio), podrías sumar dichos valores de esta manera:

Datos de entrada (tabla t):

| columna1 | columna2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 33, 0.1 |
| 8 | 20, -4.76 |
| 1897 | 200 , -25.76 |

Query sql:

```
SELECT t.columna1, sum(u.val::float) AS suma
FROM t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(string_to_array(columna2, ', ')) AS u(val)
GROUP BY t.columna1;
```

Salida:

| columna1 | suma |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 33.1 |
| 8 | 15.24 |
| 1897 | 174.24 |

Si, por otro lado, la tabla t tuviera esta estructura:

| columna1 | columna2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 33 |
| 3 | 0.1 |
| 8 | 20 |
| 8 | -4.76 |
| 1897 | 200 |
| 1897 | -25.76 |

Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es agrupar por la columna1 y sumar los valores de la columna2:

```
SELECT t.columna1, sum(t.columna2) AS suma
FROM t
GROUP BY t.columna1;
```

Comment: okay . A la segunda si  que había llegado. y respecto a la primera a que hace referencia el u(val) hace de alias de otra tabla o es el nombre para el campo .

Comment: esto agrupa por user_id y deja la columna amount con todas las cantidades que el grupo 2 o el 6 o el 10 tienen                                                                                                                       
SELECT pos_order.user_id, ARRAY_to_string(array_agg(pos_order.amount_paid),' ,') AS vsuma
FROM pos_order
GROUP BY pos_order.user_id ;

Comment: u.val es la columna que tiene los valores de la columna2 pero un solo valor por fila (para poder agrupar y sumarlos).

Comment: Redacté dos respuestas porque no me termina de quedar claro cual es la estructura de tu tabla. No conozco tu modelo de datos, pero por lo general no es buena idea guardar en una columna valores separados por comas (dificulta las queries).